# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when debugging/logging/inspecting an Object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given a class definition as below, I am getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` when trying to see which properties the Object has.

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    Person.prototype.inspect = function () {
        console.log(this);
    };
    return Person;
})();

var radek = new Person("Radek", 28);
radek.inspect();
```

In browser (Chrome), we will get the following though:

```
Person {name: "Radek", age: 28, inspect: function}
```

Answer (score 3):

Funny you should ask. By default custom `inspect()` functions defined on the objects being inspected will be called when we try to inspect them. This leads into a recursion with no end in our case.

To alleviate the problem while preserving the name use the `util` module passing an extra option `customInspect` into `inspect()`:

```
var util = require("util");

var Person = (function () {
    function Person(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    Person.prototype.inspect = function () {
        console.log(util.inspect(this, { 'customInspect': false }));
    };
    return Person;
})();

var radek = new Person("Radek", 28);
radek.inspect();
```

Which will give us the following:

`{ name: 'Radek', age: 28 }`

Comment: +1 Funny that you ask and answer. Neat issue too... I could see some people grinding their head into sandpaper over this.